# IIS7 Handler Mappings

Tags: asp.net, dll, iis-7, com, loading

I have an ASP.NET web site that performs flawlessly on my home PC. But not so well when I run it from my host provider. I need to call a COM DLL in my code behind. The local IIS7 always finds the DLL, specified as "C:\MyDLL.dll" in my DLL Import Attribute. The problem is that, whenever the code that has the call to my DLL executes, nothing happens on the page. It is as though the code never executes? So, in an effort to pinpoint the problem at my end, I undertook to setup a Win2k8 Server in my home, running IIS7, to replicate my host provider environment. It took a while to figure how to bring my site into IIS7 but, today, I'm finally able to have my site execute. BUT! I was expecting better logging? Seems the extent of Logging on IS7 is limited to recording which pages loads and when? :(

I haven't dug into Tracing yet. That maybe my next option but I wonder whether "Handler Mappings" can do anything to help loading my COM DLL? Could be a permission thing?

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question over here with some techniques that may help you troubleshoot:
[Web service works in asp.net but not IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415637/web-service-works-in-asp-net-but-not-iis)

Namely:

- Differences in user context between your local server (not sure which web server you are using...e.g. IIS Express in Visual Studio?), and the process identity on your IIS 7 App Pool.
- Trust level in ASP.NET, which can be configured on the machine. However it sounds like you are working with a web hosting company, which typically don't allow web apps to run in Full Trust (unless you have a whole VM for example).
- On your home server, you could check the Windows event logs and see if you note any errors being written when you trigger the code (for example, check the Application Log and Security Log). Also, you could try running one of the free SysInternals tools, like Process Explorer or Process Monitor (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb795533.aspx), which allows you to see in real time the accesses and failures to resources on the machine.

Comment: Thank's for your help. I'm still in the dark. I have no idea what the source of the behavior is. I read about impersonation but I'm not sure that this is the problem. User context? No idea for sure until I can trace execution up to the call to my external DLL function. Otherwise, I have no idea what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'll be damned. On my PC, I have my precious DLL sitting at "C:\myDLL.DLL" and it works flawlessly from VisualStudio2013. For as long as I stubbornly insisted on placing my DLL at the same location (why not?) on my test Win2k8 64-bit Server box, running IIS7, nothing happened when my C# was trying to call my DLL function fro within Internet Explorer (or Firefox or Chrome). Nothing, nada, zilch, rien du tout :(

At the suggestion of user2731610, I used ProcessMonitor to check whether my DLL was accessed at all by the ASP process worker. ProcessMonitor was showing that the DLL was found, and correctly "created" and "opened" and "queriedInternals" but nothing ever happened beyond that point?

I used DependencyWalker on my DLL and found that NT.dll and Kernel32.dll were referenced in myDLL.dll. I reasoned that, perhaps, myDLL.dll needed to reside at the *same* location as those other two DLLs? So I moved myDLL to C:\Windows\System32, and also C:\Windows\SysWOW64. Why not? I decided to place a copy in both locations, in case. Because I remember, when I ran ProcessMonitor earlier that ASP systematically queried more than one location in search of my DLL? Possibly all the locations contained in the PATH statement? Is it ever complicated...

DependencyWalker shows 3 entries in my DLL. First, Kernel32.DLL, CPU = x64. Second, NTDLL.DLL, CPU = x64. Third, myDLL, CPU = x86. The different CPU "types" is flagged as an error by DependencyWalker as "Modules with different CPU types"? I believe myDLL is compiled as 32-bit whereas Kernel32 and NTDLL are compiled as 64-bit. Still, it does not seem to matter.

Under Security, I added IIS_IUSRS user and gave it full control. This setting may not make a difference but, in the course of trying to diagnose the problem, it was a likely candidate.

In closing, I would like to say that I spent way far too much time on this issue and that I extensively search the net for help. I am dismayed that out of everything article and posts I stumbled upon, nothing really made clear what was going on. I guess COM is considered old technology and new resources are going to managed solutions.

This is the end of a long and frustrating research. I couldn't see the light at the end of the tunnel and was about to curse Microsoft. Thank you for your help and patience.